# Is the hyperplane a closed surface?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry

According to the [Wikipedia article on surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Closed_surfaces)

> A closed surface is a surface that is compact and without boundary.

Then is the hyperplane considered as a closed surface?

If not, then what is the surface classification of the hyperplane?

Comment: An hyperplane is not bounded, hence it is not compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you maybe getting confused between ambiguous uses of the term closed. In terms of general topology, (one of the tags you have used) a hyperplane is closed:
(If hyperplane in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is given by $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 +... +a_nx_n = c$, then it is the pre-image of closed $\{c\} \in \Bbb{R}$ under continuous map $f(x_1, x_2,...,x_n) =  a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 +... +a_nx_n $.
And it is separately a surface when we are in 3-dimensions.
However as you mentioned, a plane in 3-D is not what is known as a **"closed surface"** as it is not bounded, and hence not compact.

Comment: It may be useful to note that that a hyperplane in generality is not even a **surface.** These are objects in which every point has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to an open subset of euclidean space $E^2$. This is reasonably obvious, in the case of a hyperplane in 2-D space we have just a line, and the above statement becomes a homeomorphism from an open inteval to a disc in $E^2$.

Comment: To see this last claim would be ridiculous; consider the a homeomorphism $f$ between the two and then remove a point $\{x\}$ from the interval.   $f$ is still a homeomorphism betwen the interval minus the point $x$ and the disc minus point $f(x)$ - However the broken interval is not connected whilst the punctured disc is - a contradiction...